# Ionic 2 device ready did not fire within 2000ms

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm working within `ionic 2 beta 11` on **IOS** platforms after run the app using `ionic run ios` a **`white screen`** appear and got the below message:

```
Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
```

**Any suggestion about that ? What's the problem exactly ?**

Answer (score 10):

This could be happening due to several issues, so you'd have to try a few things:

1. Reinstall the platform by running `ionic state reset --platform`
2. Reinstall your plugins by running `ionic state reset --plugins` before doing this please check that all your plugins are included in your `package.json` file.
3. Just like @joshmorony says [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-rc-1-ios-build-device-ready-not-fired-because-of-plugin-problem/67262/9), try by changing the `Content-Security-Policy` from your `index.html` for this one:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *”>
   ```

Comment: According to these two threads: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/904 and https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1324 , the `state` commads are deprecated. Instead, while adding the platform and plugins `--save` is used to add the same to the `config.xml`. To reset plugins and platform, delete the respective folders and issue `ionic prepare`

Comment: `ionic state reset --plugins` solved my problem in fast way, thanks

Comment: none of this worked for me. i am using ionic 1 with 21 plugins

Comment: Unless you have a copy of project please don't remove/reset plugins. Because sometimes when you try to add plugins it will give very weird errors especially with plugins like Cordova push. I tried all the above and nothing worked for me.

Comment: @Vasanth you can always remove the platform and then add the plugins again. What errors did it throw?

Comment: Just now I did ionic state reset --plugins all the plugins that I had in my project was removed.Except the 5 plugins(keyboard, console, status bar etc) that will be added during project creations.

Comment: But before running that command, were the removed plugins added in the `package.json` file and in the `config.xml` file? If they were not included there (by using the `--save` flag) when installing them, the CLI  won't know that they must be added when running `ionic state reset --plugins `

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in a comment of the other answer, in new version of the CLI you should delete the `plugins` and `platforms` folders manually. 
Then run :

```
ionic cordova prepare
```