# Ionic App Calling Native iOS function, Error: Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application in iOS, where we are presenting a native screen and calling a webservice there. after getting response from server we are sending response again to ionic screen and dismissing the native screen.

But the callback is not working getting

WARN: Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.

```
 this.nativewebview.nativeMethod({}).subscribe((result) => {

  console.log('SUCCESS API CALL FROM NATIVE ------ >>>>> ');

   this.handleCloseWebView();


}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);

});
```

And iOS code is

```
- (void)nativeMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    [self apiCall command:command];
}

-(void)apiCall command:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)wsCommand {

    [webViewController callCheckoutWebService completionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable result) {
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:result];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:wsCommand.callbackId];
        NSLog(@"=======1");
    }];

}
```

can anyone tell me what might be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014332/ionic-2-device-ready-did-not-fire-within-2000ms ?

Comment: Yes I tried it. @SurajRao